# Add Tooltip over a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a button which copies into clipboard content from variable using TypeScript and Material-UI. I tried this:

```
const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState('');

const copyToClipBoard = async (text: string) => {
    try {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyMe);
        setCopySuccess('Copied!');
    } catch (err) {
        setCopySuccess('Failed to copy!');
    }
};
```

Button to call above code:

```
<Button                                    
    onClick={() => copyToClipBoard('some text to copy')}
>
    Copy Url
</Button>
```

Do you know how I can add Tooltip https://mui.com/components/tooltips/ over the button to display message for successful copy when the text is copied?

Comment: Why did you decide on making your copySuccess variable a string? Wouldn't a boolean value be more intuitive in this situation?

Comment: Because for different buttons I will need to copy different messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `controlled` [version](https://mui.com/components/tooltips/#controlled-tooltips) of the MUI tooltip to manually open and close the tooltip on some event.

The updated code could be something like below to show and hide the tooltip.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Tooltip from "@mui/material/Tooltip";

export default function ControlledTooltips() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [copyFeedback, setCopyFeedback] = React.useState("");
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const copyToClipBoard = async (text) => {
    try {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
      setCopyFeedback("Copied Successfully");
      setOpen(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("INSIDE ", { open }, err);
      setCopyFeedback("Failed to copy. Please check browser persmissions");
      setOpen(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Tooltip
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      title={copyFeedback}
      leaveDelay={500}
    >
      <Button onClick={() => copyToClipBoard("Text to Copy")}>
        Controlled
      </Button>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledtooltips-material-demo-forked-5yuif?file=/demo.js:0-925)

Comment: I have one small request. How I can also change the button label from "Controlled" to "Copied" when I press the button?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you can use the `open` prop to change the button label. e.g. something like this `{open ? "Copied" : "Controlled"}`. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledtooltips-material-demo-forked-5yuif?file=/demo.js:876-908) updated. Please review.

Comment: I found one issue. I tested the code with several buttons. When I click on one button all tooltips are visible and buttons are pressed. Do you know how this issue can be fixed?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledtooltips-material-demo-forked-5yuif?file=/demo.js). One of the approach is, instead of using the boolean to open the tootlip, we can save a specific identifier per button and use that to open a particular buttons' tooltip. I've used some simple approach to show, how it can work, but if you've a long list of buttons, you can create an array and map that array to generate repeating markup.

Comment: Thank you for the fix.

Comment: I have one small request: I tried to implement the code in Typescript but I get for example `open={open === 1}`  error `TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.` Can you edit the code into Typescript please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov please check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledtooltips-material-demo-forked-5yuif?file=/demo.tsx)